# What does this mean: Objects are reference counted across processes.

Tags: android

What does this statement mean and what are its implications:

> Objects are reference counted across processes.

Its from the android [interprocess documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) in the additional notes section.

Does it have something to do with garbage collection (doesn't each process collect its own objects)?

Comment: It's explained in http://elinux.org/Android_Binder and the linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

I read the link given to me by @mparaz in which google framework engineer Diane Hackborn discusses Android Binder.

This is what I understood from the link:

Android Binder is another In-Kernel IPC method which is very tightly integrated into all aspects of the core of Android (from the UI on down to the base level of the system). It combines aspects of process management with interprocess communication. It is written as a kernel module which bypasses/reimplements some linux process control mechanisms.

As far as I can understand it seems that if you use this type of interprocess communication you can never be sure that your objects will be garbage collected, even when your application shuts down, unless the application you are communicating with also shuts down and that application has not communicated in the same way with any other application (which again you can never be sure of unless its yours).

So basically, it seems to me like you shouldn't rely on garbage collection of your objects if you pass them around in this way. Other then that one can proceed as normal.

EDIT 1:
On a related note, it seems like sometimes this method of IPC must be closed manually (versus abandoned) or else it can crash your application (see [Call your LicenseChecker's onDestroy() method to close IPC connections](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)).

Comment: Also, it's not in the link and I'm not sure if you know about it, but reference counting is a much simpler way of tracking objects than garbage collection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting